# Print from Java App uses only top left quarter of page with Windows 7

Tags: java, printing

I tried nearly everything now. Search for days in the net. Found several solutions but not one of them works for me. 
I create a really big BufferedImage and draw its content inside. Then I want to print this scaled on an A4 paper. On OSX the printig is fine, but under Windows7 the image is only printed on the top left quarter of the page in half of the papers size. Looks like it is scaled to much.

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) throws PrinterException 
{
    this.graphics=(Graphics2D)g;

    this.graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_DEFAULT);

    // We have only one page, and 'page'
    // is zero-based
    if (this.canceled || page >= this.template.pageList.size()) 
    {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    int  x = (int)pageFormat.getImageableX() + 1;
    int  y = (int)pageFormat.getImageableY() + 1;

    int leftBorder=Math.max(x,(int)pageFormat.getWidth()/12); // Für Heftrand

    int width=(int)pageFormat.getWidth()-x-leftBorder;
    int height=(int)pageFormat.getHeight()-2*y;

    BufferedImage off_Image =  new BufferedImage(width*scale, height*scale, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); // scale is a constant of 8 atm
    this.pageWidth=width*scale;
    this.pageHeight=height*scale;
    this.graphics = off_Image.createGraphics();
    this.createSheet(page); // draw content in the image

    g.drawImage(off_Image, leftBorder, y, width,height, this);
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

I tried to use Paper and Book. For example the last of many tries was

```
    PageFormat pPageFormat = printJob.defaultPage();
    Paper pPaper = pPageFormat.getPaper();
    pPaper.setImageableArea(1.0, 1.0, 800 - 2.0, 500 - 2.0); // 800 and 500 only to test if there is any reaction but it isn't.
    pPageFormat.setPaper(pPaper);
    pPageFormat = printJob.pageDialog(pPageFormat);
    Book pBook = new Book();
    pBook.append(this, pPageFormat);
    printJob.setPageable(pBook);
```

but always the printer is only printig the image on the top left quarter of the page. In this quarter it uses the paper size I set. So when I set the para size to half of A4, I get only a width of 1/4 of A4. Same with the height. When I set the paper size to double of A4 it prints the image in the correct size, but crops it at the half of the page.

Has anyone an idea what I can do?

Thanks in advance

Claus

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Sorry no, in the end I decided to create a PDF and print this from within my application.

Comment: My Problem is: I try to print a PDF and face this problem :D